# Pgadmin couldn't connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

installed pgadmin3 from ubuntu store

[image]

```
Server doesn't listen
The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "my ip" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5433? 
If you encounter this message, please check if the server you're trying to contact is actually running PostgreSQL on the given port. Test if you have network connectivity from your client to the server host using ping or equivalent tools. Is your network / VPN / SSH tunnel / firewall configured correctly? 
For security reasons, PostgreSQL does not listen on all available IP addresses on the server machine initially. In order to access the server over the network, you need to enable listening on the address first. 
For PostgreSQL servers starting with version 8.0, this is controlled using the "listen_addresses" parameter in the postgresql.conf file. Here, you can enter a list of IP addresses the server should listen on, or simply use '*' to listen on all available IP addresses. For earlier servers (Version 7.3 or 7.4), you'll need to set the "tcpip_socket" parameter to 'true'. 
You can use the postgresql.conf editor that is built into pgAdmin III to edit the postgresql.conf configuration file. After changing this file, you need to restart the server process to make the setting effective. 
If you double-checked your configuration but still get this error message, it's still unlikely that you encounter a fatal PostgreSQL misbehaviour. You probably have some low level network connectivity problems (e.g. firewall configuration). Please check this thoroughly before reporting a bug to the PostgreSQL community.
```

And

```
netstat -nlp | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28429/postgres      
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     35558    28429/postgres       /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     35556    28429/postgres       /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Comment: Acess this link to solve your question.
http://www.mkfoster.com/2008/12/21/setting-up-postgresql-on-linux-and-connecting-using-pgadmin-iii/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see on netstat postgresql listen on 127.0.0.1 only. You must use 127.0.0.1 address in pgadmin configuration, or allow bind postgresql to "my ip".